# Expanding width of form <label> issue

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to pull in the text from the right, 'I am filling out this form as an individual' so it is fits on one line. There seems to be a 'block' preventing it from stretching out. Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9M8FQ/ If I adjust the width of the label, it adjusts every field but I really want it far over to the left anyway. Here is a screenshot of how i am trying to get it http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/images/screen.jpg

Here is the code:

```
<div class="myclass active"  id="right_box">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
      <td height="0" colspan="2" valign="middle"><label class="desc" id="Name"  for="Name">Before filling out the form, please select an option below: <span id="req_2"  class="req" style="color:#82cff5;">*</span></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="0">
      <td width="30" height="0" align="left" valign="middle" style="padding-left:7px;"><input type="checkbox" id="individual" name="FilledInBy_Individual" value="Yes" onClick="unCheck(this.id);" <%=ind%> />
      </td>
      <td height="0" valign="middle" style="padding-left:7px;"><label for="option2">I am filling out this form as an Individual</label>
      </td>
      <tr height="0">
      <td width="30" height="0" align="left" valign="middle" style="padding-left:7px;">   <input type="checkbox" id="agencyconsultant" name="FilledInBy_Agency" value="Yes" onClick="unCheck(this.id);" <%=agent%>/>
      </td>
      <td height="0" valign="middle" style="padding-left:7px;"><label for="option2">I am filling out this form as an Agency Consultant</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="0">
      <td width="30" height="0" align="left" valign="middle" style="padding-left:7px;"> <input type="checkbox" id="friendrelative" name="FilledInBy_FriendRelative" value="Yes" onClick="unCheck(this.id);" <%=friend%>/>
      </td>
      <td height="0" valign="middle" style="padding-left:7px;"><label for="option3">I am filling out this form as a friend or relative</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <td height="0" colspan="2"><%   if request.cookies("Filled_error") <> "" then %>
          <div id="firstname_error" class="errorActive" style="position:relative;">Please select an appropriate option</div>
          <%    end if %>
    </td height="0">
      </table>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
label {
clear: both;
float: left;
padding-right: 10px;
width: 240px;
}

input{
float: left;
width: 425px;
}
.myclass {
border-width: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 25px;
-webkit-border-radius: 25px;
border-radius: 25px;
color: #000000;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:5px;
}
#right_box {
width: 700px;
float: left;
margin-left: 33px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-left: 15px;
background-color:#eaeaea;
}
```

EDIT. Even adjusting the label width just pushes the text to the right on one line, it just won'\t move anymore left because of this 'wall'

Comment: Well, your checkboxes are 425 pixels wide, and your labels only 240 pixels. You could start by removing all those widths from the css (and the width attributes from the HTML) and take it from there.

Comment: Oh, another question. Why do the checkboxes and the labels for the checkboxes have to be in different table cells?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the large input width which pushes the right text away.. but it doesn't seems so because of the center.

Here's a [demo](http://tinyurl.com/nfhg9hv).

Comment: This is all correct but they have to be 425px wide for the layout I want. If I remove all widths from the css, the fields are all over the place with no alignment. Can I not create a new class just for the checkboxes perhaps? I was stupidly assuming input areas and checkboxes would have 2 different styles

Comment: Can I ask why you are working in tables anyways? In DIV it's way easier to fix this..

Comment: Long story, this form has been going on for a while now and I involved a programmer as needed a few dynamic things adding to it. I'm just trying to get the thing completed now so as they did it in tables, I left it like that. I tried with divs but it messes up the javascript extras I already have so felt it best to leave it as is!

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
input[type='checkbox'] {width:auto}
```

in the css. That will take care of the checkboxes. There's still the matter of the widths of the labels though...

Comment: This did the trick for this particular issue although not aligned up with the checkboxes. This is how it looks now http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/images/screen2.jpg The label width is correct as it is, they are text fields so want to be this wide. The other thing I need to work out is how to adjust length of these labels (I am filling out this form as an individual...) so they fit on one line without adjusting the rest of the labels.....

Comment: In response to Mr. Lister's comment 'Why do the checkboxes and the labels for the checkboxes have to be in different table cells?' there is no definitive answer for this. Like I said, i have some javascript additions on the form which didn't work when I didn't use the tables, also didn't work when I tried putting the checkbox labels and checkboxes in the same table cells. I don't know enough about tables to inker with that